# TeX truncating output of \showbox command

Tags: tex-core

I am studying Knuth's "The TeXbook". In Chapter 12, he demonstrates the glue that TeX puts between words by looking at the contents of hboxes in internal diagnostic format. I am trying to use `\showbox` command to generate the output myself like below.

```latex
\setbox0=\hbox{''Oh, oh!'' cried Baby Sally. Dick and Jane laughed.}
\showbox0
```

TeX generates the output but it is truncated after the first word (with etc.).

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x228.2227
.\tenrm " (ligature '')
.\tenrm O
.\tenrm h
.\tenrm ,
.\glue 3.33333 plus 2.08331 minus 0.88889
.etc.


! OK.
```

How can I make TeX print the full output for the whole sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want here is to increase `\showboxbreadth` (and possibly `\showboxdepth` too). To show everything you can use `\maxdimen`:

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
```

otherwise you set them to the value you want.

Here's the TeXBook description for these parameters:

> `\showboxbreadth` (maximum items per level when boxes are shown)
>   `\showboxdepth` (maximum level when boxes are shown)

The default in Plain TeX is:

```
\showboxbreadth=5
\showboxdepth=3
```

which explains why TeX shows only the first 5 items: `"Oh,\glue`. If you had a (rather odd) `\setbox0=\hbox{\hbox{''\hbox{\hbox{Oh,} ooh!}''}}`, the log would show:

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x48.0557
.\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x48.0557
..\tenrm " (ligature '')
..\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x38.05566
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x16.11116 []
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm o
...\kern0.27779
...\tenrm o
...etc.
..\tenrm " (ligature '')
```

and here you can see that only the contents of the first three boxes is shown, and what would be the fourth is just shown as `\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x16.11116 []` (the trailing `[]` means that it was truncated) because `\showboxdepth` is 3, and as before, the longer boxes (the third here) is truncated with an `etc.`.

Comment: Thanks! I set them to `\maxdimen` as you suggested. I also discovered the `\tracingall` macro which does that too apart from enabling `\tracingonline` which shows the output in the tex shell too.

Comment: @SigmaPiEpsilon Yes, `\tracingall` is the cry for help when debugging TeX code :-)